# Change Properties of multiple diagrams in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to change the properties of multiple diagrams together rather than clicking on them one by one. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Which properties do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to change all the diagrams to have Printing option scale to 1 page. This is under Diagram Properties>Diagrams>Advanced> (Radio button) Scale to 1 Page. I have lots of diagrams and some of them might be a bit bigger and when I take a pdf of the diagram it always slices it into many pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scripting facility of Enterprise Architect to loop the diagrams you would like to change and update them.
See [this section of the manual](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/automation/the_scripter_window.html) to get help.

There is a bunch of example scripts included with EA, either from the local scripts, or from the EAScriptLib MDG.

Another source of examples is my Github repository: https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library

Comment: Thank you I will try them. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a SQL to manipulate your database. `t_diagram.PDATA` holds a long cryptic string where one part is `ScalePI=0;` (which is the default for no scaling). You can alter that to be `ScalePI=1;` (meaning scale to one page).

String manipulations vary from database to database. So you need to write your own which you can execute in a script using

```
Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_diagram ...")
```

Note that you should test this in a sandbox first since invalid SQLs can easily disrupt your whole repository.